# Create global variable or variable user/group rpm

Tags: global-variables, rpm, rpmbuild, verify

I have a problem. Depending on the plattform my files in the rpm have different users/groups.
The problem is you already shoud see the right attributes of the rpm with `rpm -V` so I can't change the Attributes in the %post section because this will always show the user has been changed.

Is there a way to create a global variable where I set the name of the variable user and then use it in the %files section?
I tried it with define but it does not work right:

```
%pre
HOME = path
if[true] 
    %define USER example1 
    useradd -m -r -c $HOME $USER
else 
    %define USER example2
    useradd -m -r -c $HOME $USER
fi
%files 
%defattr(-, %{USER}, ...)
```

This gives me the error warning: user example2 does not exist - using root

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: RPM also has `%global`, however `%files` is processed when building the RPM, while `%post` is processed during install.

Comment: Yes you're right, thank you but this doesn't make my case easier. I can't change the value of the global Variable in the `%build` section

Comment: The usual way to do this is to use the same *names* on different platforms, but allow the user-id and group-id (numbers) to differ.

Comment: @ThomasDickey IMHO, you shouldn't be using absolute UID/GID anyway, and just using the same names.

Comment: @ThomasDickey That is what I feared, but I wanted to know if there was a way to do that, because I cannot change the user names for that package.

Answer (score 3):

%files is evaluated and installed before %post is executed. The user must exist in advance. Therefore:

At very top of spec file puth

```
%global USERNAME example1
%global GROUPNAME example1
```

and then in %pre put:

```
%pre
getent group %{GROUPNAME} >/dev/null || groupadd -r %{GROUPNAME}
getent passwd %{USERNAME} >/dev/null || \
    useradd -r -g %{GROUPNAME} -d HOMEDIR -s /sbin/nologin \
    -c "Useful comment about the purpose of this account" %{USERNAME}
exit 0
```

For more information see:
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:UsersAndGroups?rd=Packaging/UsersAndGroups#Dynamic_allocation

Comment: Could you please explain this? The link does't give mutch information about this case. How can I set the condition? I mean variable like mutable

Comment: you can put that condition at very begging of %pre and define the username there. My main point was that you need to do that in %pre rather than in %post.

Comment: Also, if you have subpackages, make sure that all subpackages `Requires(pre)` the main package. Otherwise, they can be installed out-of-order at the same time, and the user won't be there yet at the install of the subpackage, but will be at the end of the transaction, fulfilling the standard `Requires`. I ran into that problem the other day.

Comment: Yes you're right in the `%post` section this would cause an error. I fixed that in my question.
Still even if the conditions and definitions are in the ´%pre´ or ´%build´ section, the build of the .rpm doesn't get the information I am trying to hand over.

Answer (score 0):

I pretty sure that this is not best practice but I found a way:

```
%build
 if [condition]; then
    %global USERNAME example1
else
    %global USERNAME example2
fi
```

And later in the `%pre` section I can add the user, in case he does not exists.

Then I can use this variable user in the files section just as in my question with `%attr(-, %{USERNAME}, ...)`

If I would define the global variable at the beginning of the file
(`%global USERNAME example0`), the build would simply use the value defined there and ignore the changed values in the `%build`.